# Why is it necessary to quote Perl version string for JSON encoding?

Tags: json, perl, oop

For some Perl diagnostic tests, I'm recording assorted bits of information formatted as JSON using JSON::MaybeXS.

I get an error when I want to record the current Perl version, which I obtain from the special variable $^V.

As the minimal demonstration script shows, the error occurs unless I quote $^V as "$^V".

## json_perl_version_test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.18;

use JSON::MaybeXS;

say "Running Perl version $^V";

my $item    = 'Wut?';

my %hash1   = (
    something   => $item,
    v_unquoted => $^V
);
eval { say say 'Hash1: ', encode_json \%hash1 };
say "Oops - JSON encode error: $@" if $@;

my %hash2   = (
    something   => $item,
    v_quoted => "$^V"
);
say 'Hash2: ', encode_json \%hash2;

# Running Perl version v5.34.0
# Oops - JSON encode error: encountered object 'v5.34.0', 
# but neither allow_blessed, convert_blessed nor allow_tags
# settings are enabled (or TO_JSON/FREEZE method missing) at
# /Users/bw/Documents/Dev/tests/json_perl_version_test.pl line 17.

# Hash2: {"something":"Wut?","v_quoted":"v5.34.0"}
```

Note that it wasn't necessary to quote $item.

The error message refers to some ways to handle other cases, but seemingly not including canonical Perl version dotted-decimal strings. I've looked through the main Perl JSON modules (recent versions of JSON::MaybeXS, JSON, and Cpanel::JSON::XS), but can't find anything referring to $^V or dotted-decimal strings. Also don't find a relevant question on SO :(.

Perhaps I'm missing something? Or am I stuck with needing to quote $^V?

Reasons?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`$^V` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%5EV) is really an object

> The revision, version, and subversion of the Perl interpreter, represented as a [version](https://perldoc.perl.org/version) object.

An object cannot be stored in JSON just so.  Quoting it stringifies it.

---

It is possible to make `JSON::XS` (and its `Cpanel::`) take a blessed reference but it involves more work. See [Object Serialization](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS#OBJECT-SERIALIZATION). The cleanest complete solution is with [convert_blessed](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS#$json-=-$json-%3Econvert_blessed-(%5B$enable%5D)), when the `encode` method will look for a `TO_JSON` method (in the class of the object that is to be added to JSON), which would return a JSON-ready string.

Alas, there is no such a thing for the `version` (nor for a few other classes I tried, like `DateTime`). One can add that method to the class<sup>†</sup> but just thinking of it makes quotes look nice.

Another way is to get explicit in making the `version` object stringify

```
my $json = JSON::XS->new->encode( { ver => $^V->stringify } )
```

This is yet more elaborate but at least now it's clear what the matter is, without magic quotes.

Or just quote it and add a comment.

---

<sup>†</sup>  By "monkey-patching" it, for example

- add the sub, with a fully qualified name

  ```
  perl -Mstrict -wE'use JSON::XS; say $^V; 
      sub version::TO_JSON { return $_[0]->stringify }; 
      my $json = JSON::XS->new->convert_blessed->encode( { ver => $^V } ); 
      say $json'
  ```

  Can also add a sub via string `eval` at runtime but that doesn't seem needed.
- write the code reference to the class's symbol table at runtime

  ```
  perl -wE'use JSON::XS; say $^V; 
      *{"version"."::"."TO_JSON"} = sub { return $_[0]->stringify }; 
      $json = JSON::XS->new->convert_blessed->encode( { ver => $^V } ); 
      say $json'
  ```

  well, or really with `strict` in effect we need to allow the symbolic refs

  ```
  perl -Mstrict -wE'use JSON::XS; say $^V; 
      NO_STRICT_REFS: { 
          no strict "refs"; 
          my ($class, $method) = qw(version TO_JSON);
          *{$class."::".$method} = sub { return $_[0]->stringify } 
      }; 
      my $json = JSON::XS->new->convert_blessed->encode( { ver => $^V } ); 
      say $json'
  ```

  where I also added variables for class name and method, not necessary but better.

  This is packaged for far nicer use in [Sub::Install](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Install)

  ```
  use Sub::Install;
  Sub::Install::install_sub({
      code => sub { ... }, into => $package, as => $subname
  });
  ```

  There are expected defaults and a bit more in the module.

Or, of course by writing a wrapper class or some such but that's something yet else.

Comment: As is often the case, it was right there in the error message: "encountered object 'v5.34.0' ..."  *object* was the word whose significance I missed. Thx

Comment: @BruceVanAllen Yup, a clue is usually somewhere around -- but that sole hint with the "_object_" word in the error message can easily slip past.  Fyi, I added examples of monkey-patching it so that JSON can do its thing with the object.  Not that youo'd want this over simple quotes or `->stringify`, but if that JSON comes up a lot this may actually  be useful?  Or it may come handy otherwise. Thus this note

Answer (score 3):

Blessed Perl objects can't be stored in JSON without extra steps (mentioned by the error).

```
print ref $^V;  # version
```

A possible workaround:

```
my $j = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->convert_blessed;  # Allow stringification.
say 'Hash1: ', $j->encode(\%hash1);
```